# How do I get a token in a plain Java console application?

Tags: java, angular, spring, keycloak

I use keycloak to secure the login of an angular frontend against a spring boot backend. This works so far well. For this I use the implicit flow and angular-oauth2-oidc.

Now to my question: I have a 3rd application which is a plain java console application (batch job without user interaction). This application should also be able to communicate with the backend rest api, but with a fixed token or via username/password.

How can I get a bearer token in a console application? Is there an API and an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the same approach you used in your angular application to request the token, but with Spring's `RestTemplate`?

So first you get the token by calling the authentication service, and then once you get it successfully you add it to your header as an `Authorization: Bearer <token>` with subsequent requests to the actual backend REST API doing the business logic.

Spring has a library with some OAuth2 facilities too, which you might want to look into. 
https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html
Check the part describing OAuth 2.0 Client. It seems to indicate there is some extension to the `RestTemplate` to add the right headers.

Personally I usually just manage the token myself and add it to the header as I build the request for the `RestTemplate`.

Comment: In the angular app I used the angular-oauth2-oidc framework. Here I only had to enter the data for the keycloak server and the framework did the rest. But I don't know how to assemble the request to the keycloak server manually.

Comment: @DennisG. Check the link I posted, it seems to provide a similar facility, with the configuration of secrets etc. which then automatically adds the right headers to the RestTemplate. Otherwise you can do it yourself if you know the keycloak endpoint and what it is expecting... it is just one call in the beginning to get the token before you start doing the work you want to do on the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

For schedule jobs/background jobs, where user is not currently logged-in, you use 
[offline tokens][1].

You need to create user for system usage and assigned offline_access role.
and then generate offline token and store it in data store like database.

In your console application use offline token to generate access token and use it as bearer token for accessing the back-end rest api.

http://blog.keycloak.org/2015/12/offline-tokens-in-keycloak.html

Comment: this not relevant to above question , can you please tell me where i found refresh token in spring boot code ?

Comment: Better ask as separate question, you can get  KeycloakPrincipal principal = (KeycloakPrincipal) request.getUserPrincipal();